# Interaction Energy vs Force

Tags: forces, energy, coulombs-law, interactions

I'm having a hard time determining the relationship/differences between interaction energy and forces. Say we have a system of two charged particles. Each particle will exert a force on each other (from [Coulomb's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law)), but also defined is an interaction energy between the two particles given by Coulomb's Law multiplied by the distance between them (reducing the $r^2$ term in Coulomb's Law to just $r$).

How are these concepts related? What is the correct way to interpret the interaction energy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force is just the gradient of the potential energy. So it's not true that the energy is just force multiplied by $r$. It is the integral of the force w.r.t. $r$, which gives you the $1/r$  dependence.

Edit: here "potential energy" and "interaction energy" are used interchangeably.